# go test import errors

Tags: http, go, gopath

I've cloned [go source code](https://go.googlesource.com/go/) using `git clone https://go.googlesource.com/go` into my `~/godev/` directory.

My $GOPATH is `~/gocode`

I installed go using the installer

If I cd into `~/godev/go/src/net/http` and run `go test`, I get these errors:

```
h2_bundle.go:46:2: cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack (from $GOROOT)
    ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack (from $GOPATH)
h2_bundle.go:47:2: cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/idna" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/idna (from $GOROOT)
    ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net/idna (from $GOPATH)
h2_bundle.go:48:2: cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/lex/httplex" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/lex/httplex (from $GOROOT)
    ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net/lex/httplex (from $GOPATH)
transport.go:32:2: cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/proxy" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/proxy (from $GOROOT)
    ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net/proxy (from $GOPATH)
transfer.go:14:2: use of internal package not allowed
```

After I follow the directions [here](https://github.com/mailgun/godebug/issues/88#issuecomment-272671936) by doing `cd $GOPATH/src`
 followed by `cp -R /usr/local/go/src/vendor/golang_org .`, I still get these errors:

h2_bundle.go:47:2: code in directory ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net/idna expects import "golang.org/x/net/idna"
transport.go:32:2: cannot find package "golang_org/x/net/proxy" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/proxy (from $GOROOT)
    ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net/proxy (from $GOPATH)
transfer.go:14:2: use of internal package not allowed

It is true that there is no proxy package under ~/gocode/src/golang_org/x/net, but even if I fixed that somehow, I don't understand the other 2 errors.

Comment: You _must_ _not_ clone your Go compiler sources into your GOPATH. GOPATH is for _your_ _own_ packages only and _not_ for the Go compiler and tools.

Comment: Starting a new different question based on your feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702101/go-source-http-package-import-errors

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the package **golang_org** is not a root package and your code requires it for building and can't find it.Simply you have to **go get** the following package.

```
/usr/local/go/src/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack (from $GOROOT)
/Users/lf215/go/src/golang_org/x/net/http2/hpack (from $GOPATH)
```

There is some issue with this version of Go. you may refer
https://github.com/constabulary/gb/issues/635